# How to open activity of bottom navigation view from adapter? without holder

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I need to pass some data of my adapter to bottom navigation view activity. Just like this:

```
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, RestaurantDetailsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("restaurantUid", uid);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

I don't know where to put my button to use `setOnClickListener`

Comment: if you know how to do it please help me

Answer (score 0):

You should not change activities in Adapter. Rather, you should create an interface for your click listener and implement that in your Activity:

Create a Click Listener interface class **ItemClickListenerInterface.Java**

```
public interface ItemClickListener {
    void onClick(View view, int position);
}
```

Then, in your viewHolder inside your **AdapterClass**, bind this click listener to the view Like this:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    private ItemClickListener clickListener;
   
    public void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.clickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

   public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
 
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           if (clickListener != null) clickListener.onClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }
}
```

Then in Your **ActivityClass.Java**, implement this click list

```
public class CityActivity extends Activity implements ItemClickListener {

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    
        mAdapter.setClickListener(this);
}
@Override
    public void onClick(View view, int position) {
       final Resturant resturant=resturantsList.get(position)
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, RestaurantDetailsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("restaurantUid", resturant.uid);
            context.startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm stuck at Activity onCreate because there is no .setClickListener :(

Comment: you might have not correctly initialized adapter. Show me your code